Decreasing sequence of open sets all containing $p\in{X}$ with infinite intersection equal to $p$
Suppose $\{U_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a decreasing ($U_{n+1}\subset{U_n}, \forall{n}$) sequence of open sets in a
metric space $(X,d)$ such that $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}{U_n}=\{p\}$ for some $p\in{X}$. Suppose $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is a sequence of points in  such that $_ ∈ _$ for all n. Does $\{_\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ necessarily converge to $p$? Prove or construct a counterexample.
I think I have come up with a counter example, with $U_n=[-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n}]$ and $(X,d)$ being the real line equipped with the discrete metric. We have that $U_n$ is open as any subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is open in our metric space as it has the discrete metric. The intersection of $U_n$ from $n=1$ to $\infty$ equals $\{0\}$ which can be shown with the Archimedean property. The sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ given by $x_n=\frac{1}{n}$ satisfies $x_n\in{U_n}$ for all $n$. Finally as we are using the discrete metric, $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$  cannot converge to $0$ because $d(x_n,0)\geq1$ for all $n$.
I believe this is correct but I am worried I have made a mistake, because when I searched up the question online, chegg said the statement was true, but I could not see their proof because their website requires money. Also the question in the textbook said (tricky) beside it and I feel this answer is too obvious.

FWIW, your counterexample looks good to me.

The counterexample is correct. Another one is $\mathbb{N} \cup \{\infty\}$ with the discrete metric, the subsets $U_n=[n,\infty]$ and the sequence $x_n=n$.
A more promising condition would be $\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathrm{diam}(U_n)=0$, so that the sets become arbitrarily small with respect to the metric.

Thank you! I am glad to see my reasoning was correct. I'm still confused on why chegg said the statement was true but I suppose I never saw their solution, and they could have meant something otherwise.

Your example is fine. Another one: $X=\mathbb R$ with the usual topology, $U_n=(-\frac1n,\frac1n)\cup(n,\infty)$, $p=\{0\}$, $x_n=n+1$.
